# How to create dynamic queues in rabbit mq using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, queue, amqp

I need some help.

I'm developing a spring boot application, and I want wo publish messages to a rabbitMQ. I want to send it to a queue, that is named in the message itself. This way i want to create queues dynamicly.
I only found examples that use a "static" queue.

I have reserched some things but didn't find anything.
I'm new to RabbitMQ and learned the basic concepts.
I'm also fairly new to spring.

RabbotMQ Config

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Value("amq.direct")
    String exchange;

    @Value("queue-name") // Don't want to do this
    String queueName;

    @Value("routing-key") // Or this
    String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

MessageSender

```java
@Service
public class RabbitMQSender {

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate template;

    @Value("amq.direct")
    private String exchange;

    public void send(MessageDTO message) {
        template.convertAndSend(exchange, message);

    }
}
```

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241880/dynamically-add-new-queues-bindings-and-exchanges-as-beans

Comment: also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872274/spring-rabbittemplate-how-to-create-queues-automatically-upon-send

Comment: Thanks! @BenjaminSlabbert That RabbitAdmin helped a lot

Comment: How can I tag this as closed?

Comment: best way would be to post your solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted or give it an upvote

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I came to a solution:

You need to create a AmqpAdmin in your config:

```java
@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
}
```

Then you add it to your service:

```java
@Autowired
private AmqpAdmin admin;
```

Finally you can use it to create queues and bindings.

```java
Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, durable, false, false);
Binding binding = new Binding(queueName, Binding.DestinationType.QUEUE, EXCHANGE, routingKey, null);
admin.declareQueue(queue);
admin.declareBinding(binding);
```

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872274/spring-rabbittemplate-how-to-create-queues-automatically-upon-send)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of RabbitMQ you were on but, your original code was close. This works, too.

```
@Bean
Queue fanoutQueue() {
    // empty name, durable false, exclusive false, autoDelete false
    return new Queue("", false, false, true);
}

@Bean
FanoutExchange fanoutExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("fanout-exchange", true, false);
}

@Bean
Binding fanoutBinding(Queue fanoutQueue, FanoutExchange fanoutExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(fanoutQueue).to(fanoutExchange);
}
```

Comment: how this is dynamic Queue creation?